# Reduce 2d pytorch tensor to 1d tensor & Model not training cause of error in for loop

Tags: pytorch, resize, tensor, pytorch-dataloader

```
a.shape = torch.Size([32, 20])
a[0]=tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
a[9]=tensor([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

a is my tensor and to feed it to a loss function, I need to get the shape to [32].
So I want something like this

```
a[0]=1
a[9]=2..
```

I have tried torch. squeeze and torch.view at the moment.

The problem is that my loss  is not getting updated.

```
for epoch_i in range(5):
  total_loss = 0
  print(epoch_i,total_loss)

  model.train()  
  for step, batch in enumerate(train_data):
    print(step)

    train_x, train_y = tuple(t.to(device)for t in batch)
    print(train_y.shape)

    model.zero_grad()

    logits=model(train_x)

    loss_fn= nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    #print(train_y.shape,"y",train_x.shape,"x")

    loss= loss_fn(logits,train_y)
    print(loss)

    total_loss=loss+total_loss


    loss.backward()
```

```
0 0
0
torch.Size([32, 20])
tensor(3.6922, grad_fn=<NllLoss2DBackward0>)
1 0
0
torch.Size([32, 20])
tensor(3.6799, grad_fn=<NllLoss2DBackward0>)
2 0
0
torch.Size([32, 20])
tensor(3.6673, grad_fn=<NllLoss2DBackward0>)
3 0
0
torch.Size([32, 20])
tensor(3.6546, grad_fn=<NllLoss2DBackward0>)
4 0
0
torch.Size([32, 20])
tensor(3.6416, grad_fn=<NllLoss2DBackward0>)
```

I think this might be because of train_y being [32,20] instead of [32].

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, it all depends on what you want your reduction to do. In this example you seem to assume that a row always contain a single number repeated multiple times, in which case `a[:,0]` should return what you want. If not, can you detail further what you want ?

Comment: @trialNerror My loss does not get updated/added. I have added the code. Could you please take a look?

Comment: You have `total_loss = 0` immediately followed by `print(epoch_i,total_loss)`, so of course it prints zero. You probably meant to put `total_loss = 0` outside the outer for loop.